# Rails routing help pls (localized do)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-i18n

I have a working RoR4 app using route_translator gem.

Could someone please help me wrap these. No idea what I am doing, beginner here. :)

Original working routes:

```
resources :events do
 get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
 get :autocomplete_cit_name, :on => :collection
 get "search", :on => :collection
end

resources :tags
 get 'tags/autocomplete_tag_name'
```

Tried to wrap like this but no luck:

```
localized do
 resources :events 
  get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
  get :autocomplete_cit_name, :on => :collection
  get "search", :on => :collection
end

localized do
 resources :tags
  get 'tags/autocomplete_tag_name'
end
```

Error is:
/routing/mapper.rb:1390:in `collection': can't use collection outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)

ps: put the translations in my hu.yml and I have an other app whih works with this gem but I don't use autocomplete there so the wrap was easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it:

```
localized do
resources :events do
  get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
  get :autocomplete_cit_name, :on => :collection
  get "search", :on => :collection
 end
end
```